# Splitting an array at only certain places but not others

Tags: javascript, split

I understand the `.split()` function quite well. But what I can seem to figure out is how to split in certain places but not in others. Sounds confusing? Well I mean for example, lets say I use `.split(",")` on the following string:

```
div:(li,div),div
```

Is it possible to split it so that only the commas ouside of the parentheses get split.

So the `string` above with the `split` method should return:

```
['div:(li,div)', 'div']
```

Of course at the moment it is also splitting the first comma inside of the parentheses, returning:

```
['div:(li', 'div)', 'div']
```

Is there some way to make this work like I desire?

Comment: Generally, the presence of a parentheses convention in some syntax means that interpreting sentences will require a more robust parser than just a regex mechanism.

Comment: Would this be possible to make in JavaScript?

Comment: Would this work?  `/,(?!.*\))/`

Comment: Parsing, smarsing. My answer works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your expected strings are not going to become more complicated than this, you don't have to worry about writing code to parse them. Regex will work just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/dC5HN/1/

```
var str = "div:(li,div),div:(li,div),div";
var parts = str.split(/,(?=(?:[^\)]|\([^\)]*\))*$)/g);
console.log(parts);
```

outputs:

```
["div:(li,div)", "div:(li,div)", "div"]
```

Answer (score 1):

REGEX is not built for this sort of thing, which is essentially parsing.

When faced with this sort of situation previously I've first temporarily replaced the parenthesised parts with a placeholder, then split, then replaced the placeholders with the original parenthised parts.

A bit hacky, but it works:

```
    var str = 'div:(li,div),div',
        repls = [];

    //first strip out parenthesised parts and store in array
    str = str.replace(/\([^\)]*\)/g, function($0) {
        repls.push($0);
        return '*repl'+(repls.length - 1)+'*';
    });

    //with the parenthisised parts removed, split the string then iteratively
    //reinstate the removed parenthisised parts
    var pieces = str.split(',').map(function(val, index) {
        return val.replace(/\*repl(\d+)\*/, function($0, $1) {
            return repls[$1];
        });
    });

    //test
    console.log(pieces); //["div:(li,div)","div"]
```

Comment: Could you help me out with one more problem. You are suppose to be able to use as many as `div:(li,div)` (for example) as needed. But `div:(li,div),div:(li,div),div` (for example) doesnt work. Is there a fix?

Comment: Ah - I missed the global modifier on my first `replace` pattern. See edit (note the `g` after the forward slash).

Comment: On caveat to this method is parenthesis inside of parenthesis. Not sure if that's a concern with your scenario or not.   "div:((li),div),div:(li,div)" for instance

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices my answer will split `"div:(div:(li,li,li),div),div:(li,div,a),div,div:(div,div,li,div,a)"` as `["div:(div:(li,li,li),div)", "div:(li,div,a)", "div", "div:(div,div,li,div,a)"]`

Comment: My regex knowledge is somewhat limited as I don't use it often for the types of projects I do. I am genuinely curious though what the performance difference would be to this or Shmiddty's answer VS. the function I created.

Answer (score 0):

This function will split whatever you specify in splitChar, but ignore that value if inside parenthesis:

```
function customSplit(stringToSplit, splitChar){
    var arr = new Array();
    var isParenOpen = 0
    var curChar;
    var curString = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < stringToSplit.length; i++) {
        curChar = stringToSplit.substr(i, 1);
        switch(curChar) {
            case "(":
                isParenOpen++;
                break;

            case ")":
                if(isParenOpen > 0) isParenOpen--;
                break;
            case splitChar:
                if (isParenOpen < 1) {
                    arr.push(curString);
                    curString = "";
                    continue;
                }
        }

        curString += curChar;
    }
    if (curString.length > 0) {
        arr.push(curString);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that actually works like I would like, its a little long. But it'll work for now.

Comment: I'm sure it can be optimized/shrunk, but I wanted it to be readable so you know what's going on.